# How to refresh a table on the parent page when I close a popup window in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, popup, reload

I have a table on a parent page users.php, populated with datas from mySQL. I have a button on the row ADD USER that opens a popup window that allows to add an user. The button is hidden when the user is already registered. I would like to refresh only the table and not the entire page when I close the popup after the form has been submitted. How can I do it properly?

Comment: Upon closing the popup, use AJAX to load the table and replace the existing one with it. With jQuery, it's as easy as `$('#mytable').load(url_to_table_script);`

Answer (score 0):

using jquery

Create function with javascript in parent window something like

```
function reloadTable(){
 $.ajax({
 url: "tabledata.php",
 cache: false
 })
  .done(function( html ) {
    $( "#tablename" ).html( html );
  });
}
```

then in the child window use

```
    $( window ).unload(function() {
     window.opener.reloadTable();
   });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case I have to change tabledata.php with my page url, users.php?. I've tried your solution but on popup close duplicate everything from the parent page.

Comment: @Florin that sounds like a different problem/question to handle.

Comment: I have partially solved the problem by adding the table in an iframe on my page users.php. It is working , at popup close the iframe reloads, but I do not really like this way.